# Skip record in discard_all method with discard gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my User model I have

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  after_discard do
    comments.discard_all
  end

  after_undiscard do
    comments.undiscard_all
  end
```

When doing discard of a user, it's gonna go and discard all the comments. Is it posible to put a condition and not discard a comment if a comment attribute is not nil for example?

Comment: Does your `Comment` model include the corresponding `belongs_to` association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up doing

```
  after_discard do
    comments.where(status: 0).discard_all
  end

  after_undiscard do
    comments.where(deleted_by: nil).undiscard_all
  end
```